# EF core (MySql) scraffold DB-First not generate FK as class

Tags: c#, .net, ef-core-3.1, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I develop .Net core API server using .net core 3.1 with Pomelo EF core (for connect Mysql Database)

I using Database First approach for fist release scraffold generate FK attribute as Object property (Ac & Temp)

```
    public partial class Devices
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Mac { get; set; }
        public string Hostname { get; set; }
        public int? AcId { get; set; }
        public int? TempId { get; set; }
        public virtual Ac Ac { get; set; }
        public virtual Temp Temp { get; set; }
    }
```

But a few month later I re-generate after updated my DB. Scraffold not generate FK as object anymore (I'm not sure I have update Nuget Package or not) I get result look like

```
public partial class Device
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Mac { get; set; }
    public string Hostname { get; set; }
    public int? AcId { get; set; }
    public int? TempId { get; set; }
}
```

I try to googling to find how it been this way

I worry about my api result need to use .Include()

```
var target = await this.db.Devices.Include(x => x.Ac).Include(x => x.Temp).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id.Value);
if (target != null)
{
    var viewModel = this.mapper.Map<DeviceViewModel>(target);
    return Ok(viewModel);
}
```

Anyone know this is my fault or EF scraffold is changed the way to generate class and if its normal how to use .Include()

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found solution for my problem. It's my mistake I generate Schema and table by create Model on Mysql Workbench.

When generate schema default option are checked on `Skip creation foreign key` it's make Scraffold generate my expected result.

So just uncheck.